# Loops with advanced filter, new criteria every Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have this code:

```
Sub omgifthisworks()
Sheets("data").Select
Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Sheets("log").Range("A1:A4"), Unique:=False
Sheets("Data").Select
Sheets("Data").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("banks").Range("A2").Value

enter code here
```

It's function is pretty basic. Is it possible to create a Loop where this code will create as many new worksheets as I have cells in column "A" in my "banks" worksheet?
Is it also possible to have the loop move the filter criteria on column to the right and select only as many cells as there is data?

The end result that I'm hoping to achieve is code that will create many new sheets of data with different names that have data inside which is filtered by new criteria every time.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question about looping through, go here:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx

For your second:

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = [name you want]
```

Comment: I would like the name to become ActiveSheet.Name = Sheets("banks").Range("A2").Value

 for the second time it loops, and so on.

Comment: I meant A3, then A4, etc.

Comment: The links will help you loop through cells. I suggest starting there, then come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! If you have any tips on how to loop the advanced filter criteria to select new cells until we run out of data that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @sammy Are you kidding? What is this `If you have any tips on [] that would be much appreciated`?! You sentence doesn't make sense and looks like you took it from a "cute sentence website". There is nothing as **tips** for a simple `for .. next` loop. Just follow his link, it has everything you need in it.

Comment: and now you're yelling at me... over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I've used code like this to do something similar what you're talking about.

**origSh** as the Worksheet containing the original data to filter.

**filterSh** is a Worksheet containing the data for the Advanced Filter. Row 1 contains column headers to filter on; row 2 contains the data criteria to filter.

The procedure loops through the columns of filterSh and filters the data in origSh by the given criteria, copying the filtered data to new sheets placed at the end of the workbook.

```
Sub FilterToSheets(origSh As Worksheet, filterSh As Worksheet)
    Dim filterRng As Range
    Dim newSh As Worksheet

    Set newSh = filterSh
    For Each filterRng In filterSh.UsedRange.Columns
        Set newSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=newSh)
        newSh.Name = filterRng.Cells(2).Text
        origSh.UsedRange.AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            criteriarange:=filterRng, _
            copytorange:=newSh.Range("A1"), _
            unique:=False
    Next
End Sub
```

This should hopefully give you a leg up to write something that fits your example.

Comment: Thanks dude. I actually got the code I have to do the job I need perfectly. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep or whatever.